# Several iframes crop bottom

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm trying to use iframe in places where I need to edit navigations so I don't have to do it on every individual page, but I'm having an issue where it crops the bottom of my content.

Both iframes in the same page are cropped at the same height, but the only formatting I have on the iframe is "overflow: visible;". I've checked for any other overflow things that might interfere, but there's only "overflow:auto" on the middle section that doesn't interact with the iframes, and auto shouldn't cut it off anyways.

I could set them to individual set heights in pixels, but I want to avoid that so it expands if I were to add more links, which would add height to the content, thus making my attempt at not having to edit every single page useless if I solved it with a set height of pixels.

A thing I've seen mentioned before where people had trouble with it was it being inside a

, but mine aren't. I've put them inside as little other stuff as possible. I tried with a script I saw in a different post but that didn't work either.

Codepen to the entire thing [is over here](https://codepen.io/thepasteldyke/pen/qBvJKpr).

Top left iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://thepasteldyke.neocities.org/art/sfw-art/oc/pages-sfw-oc" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Top right iframe:

```
 <iframe src="https://thepasteldyke.neocities.org/art/sfw-art/oc/worlds-sfw-oc" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" ></iframe>
```

These are the iframe html I have.
Below is the css:

```
.iframe {
    overflow: visible;
  }
```

Logically I know there must be something overriding it, but I can't find it.

It has the same issue no matter if I have one or more iframes.

Comment: Iframes don’t autosize to their content in the way you think they do.

Comment: @DavidBradshaw I didn't know that. Is there something else that I can use in the same way that does autosize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the proper way to respond, but I managed to semi-solve it by adding **min- and max- height** to the iframe, but for some reason, it only worked when I put it in the HTML rather than the CSS. Anyway. It's now as size-responsive as it can get.

Answering this here cus I honestly had no idea iframe wasn't inherently size-responsive until a comment I got on my question, so uuuh, there might be others who also didn't know.